# What Type of fly is this? its huge

Tags: species-identification, entomology, diptera

[image]I found this stunningly beautiful Fly in a graveyard in Point Lonsdale Australia.  Can someone tell my what type it is Please.

It was wide as my thumbnail about 3cm long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could be a blue rutila fly (Family Tachinidae) http://www.brisbaneinsects.com/brisbane_tachinids/BlueRutiliaFly.html. Or the green rutila fly, which is similar.

Or the golden head rutila:
[image]

Comment: I believe that you have the correct family; I'm less certain the species is right.

Comment: Why down vote my post? My answer provides new information that is useful because it identifies the family of the insect, which is more than the OP had to begin with.

Comment: I am not familiar with the site,  I didn't vote you down or if I did I didn't mean to.  Picture by Perfectionist has more similar features.  Thankyou for responding.  They are quite stunning and detailed.